# Running MapReduce job on hadoop remote cluster

Tags: python, hadoop, mrjob

I would like to know if there is a method for running MapReduce Job into a Hadoop remote cluster. In my University there is a cluster which has Hadoop installed, so I have been learning MapReduce for distributing Machine Learning jobs. However, I have not found explicit information for running MapReduce job's in a remote machine that is not Amazon MR. There is some tutorial at least for running python MR in a remote machine?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The easiest possible way is connect to cluster via SSH and run jobs using bash

Comment: Thank you @maxteneff, I think it is the most convenient choice for now. Probably I could design a MrJob generic extension as future work.